# Print User input to physical printer in Golang

Tags: go, printing, println

I'm new here in Golang world for a week.. I've been research and still don't know how to print from user input to physical printer, from USB to printer.

For example I have done with code, just need add other function to print..

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

   fmt.Println("First name: ")

   var name1 string
   fmt.Scanln(&name1)
   )
   fmt.Println("Last name: ")

   var name2 string
   fmt.Scanln(&name2)

   fmt.Print("My full name is: ")
   fmt.Print(name1 + " " + name2)
}

func print(){

//need function to print directly from USB to pyhsical printer..
//print from func main() as text, any format

}
```

I have no idea to create print func in golang from user input..

If successful, then after func main() println, then immediately send the command to print to my printer.. just using terminal, I don't need the GUI.

Thank you for helping me:')

Comment: You would need to interact with the physical printer's drivers...

Comment: Not sure if any Printer API libraries exists for Go, but you could perhaps store the user input in a file and execute a sub process and call `lpr`. 
Here's one example: https://opensource.com/article/21/9/print-files-linux

(Assuming from terminal mention that you are using Linux :) )